# Is there a "measure" $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ which encodes Hausdorff measure of every dimension?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

A crazy idea...

#### Question

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, and $X$ the set of continuous functions $[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$. Does there exist a "measure" function $\mu: \mathcal{B} \to X$ satisfying the following conditions?

1. $\mu(\varnothing) = \boldsymbol{0}$.
2. For all $d \in [0,\infty)$, if $A \in \mathcal{B}$ and $\mu_d$ is [$d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure), then:
   $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\mu(A)(x)}{x^d} = \mu_d(A).$$
   (Specifically if $A$ has Hausdorff dimension $d$ and measure $a$ in that dimension, we want it to grow like $ax^d$, if $a \ne 0, \infty$.)
3. $\mu$ is countably additive, in the following sense: let $A_1, A_2, A_3, \ldots$ be disjoint Borel sets with union $A$,
   $\mu(A_n) = f_n$ and $\mu(A) = f$.
   If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n$ converges uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then

$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_n = f.
$$

**Update:** Eric Wofsey has shown below by an elementary argument that if $\mu$ also satisfies:

4. Translation-invariance: $\mu(A + r) = \mu(A)$ for all $A \in \mathcal{B}$ and $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

then this is impossible. What about 1-3?

#### Motivation

While Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$ fails to capture any size differences between different measure-zero sets, we can capture such information with the [Hausdorff dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension). By identifying a set with its Hausdorff dimension *and* its Hausdorff measure in that dimension, we get a much richer notion of size.

For example, $\varnothing$ (dimension 0 measure 0) is smaller than $\{1,4\}$ (dimension 0 measure $2$), which is smaller than $\mathbb{Q}$ (dimension 0 measure $\infty$), which is smaller than the [Cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set) (dimension $\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}$ measure $1$) which is smaller than $[0,1]$ (dimension $1$ measure $1$), which is smaller than $\mathbb{R}$ (dimension $1$ measure $\infty$).

I have long been curious: can we capture this notion of size in a single "measure" on Borel sets -- not real-valued, but function-valued? Above is a specific attempt.

Comment: Is there a reason you haven't written axiom 2 as $\lim\frac{\mu(A)(x)}{x^d}=a$ and then allowed $a$ to be $0$ or $\infty$?  In fact, with that version, you could just require $\lim\frac{\mu(A)(x)}{x^d}=\mu_d(A)$ for all $d$ (where $\mu_d$ is $d$-dimensional Hausdorff measure), without needing to mention the Hausdorff dimension of $A$ directly.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thanks, that's a very good point. I didn't know exactly what to do with measure $0$ or $\infty$ sets so I left out any conditions for them, but your approach seems more natural. I've updated axiom 2 to be what you suggested.

Comment: FYI, the middle-thirds Cantor set has measure $1$ in dimension $\frac{\ln 2}{\ln 3}.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks -- I was curious.

Comment: It took me a few minutes, but I finally found a stackexchange question/answer that shows this measure is $1$ -- [How prove that $m_\alpha ^*(\mathcal C)\geq 1$ where $\mathcal C$ is the Cantor set, and $m_\alpha $ the Hausdorff measure.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1686033/how-prove-that-m-alpha-mathcal-c-geq-1-where-mathcal-c-is-the-cantor?rq=1)

Comment: Thus may be relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115743/an-algebra-of-integrals/342651#342651

Comment: @Anixx Thanks for the link and interesting answers.

Comment: @6005, it seems to me that you are thinking about representing Housdorff measures as rates of growth of polynomials (the order of the polynomial would be the dimension, and the coefficient of the higher power would be the measure in that dimension). I also was thinking about this.

Comment: @Anixx Yes, precisely.

Answer (score 5):

This is impossible if you require translation-invariance.  Indeed, consider $A=\mathbb{N}$, $B=\{0\}$, and $C=A\setminus B$.  Then translation-invariance implies $\mu(A)=\mu(C)$, since $C=A+1$.  But axioms (1) and (3) imply that $\mu(-)(x)$ is finitely additive for each $x$, so $\mu(A)(x)=\mu(B)(x)+\mu(C)(x)$ for all $x$.  Thus $\mu(B)(x)=0$ for all $x$.  This contradicts axiom (2), since $\mu(B)(x)$ must converge to $1$ as $x\to\infty$.

(Note that ordinary $0$-dimensional Hausdorff measure avoids this problem by having $\mu(A)$ and $\mu(C)$ be infinite, so you can't subtract and deduce that $\mu(B)=0$.)

Comment: Thank you. I will leave the question in case 1-3 are still satisfiable.